# How to make Google Sheet drop down value affect other drop down

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 4 drop downs with TRUE or FALSE options. I am looking to make a formula that makes it so that if one of them is true the rest is set to false automatically.

[image]

So, in this case since Next Day is TRUE, sameday, sd 11am, rush and P2P are false. If I change Sameday to TRUE, I would like Next Day to change to False automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you would need to write a script in `google apps scripts` since each cell can only hold _either_ a value or a function but not both. In a script you could define a function and use the onEdit trigger to call it.

Comment: @a-burge true, that's the only option. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You **can't** achieve that by using a google sheet formula.
- You clearly need an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger function and therefore take advantage of [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).
- As soon as a cell in the list `['F2','G2','H2','I2','J2']` is **edited**, the script will check which cell was edited and whether the new value is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If the value is `TRUE` then it will change the values of the other cells to `FALSE`. If the newly selected value is `FALSE` then it won't do anything.

---

### Solution:

Please follow the instructions (gif). They are pretty straightforward.

Here is the code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const cellR = e.range.getA1Notation()
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const cells = ['F2','G2','H2','I2','J2'];
  
  cells.forEach(cell=>{
  var otherCells = cells.filter(val=>val!=cell);
  if(as.getName() == sheetName && cellR ==cell && as.getRange(cell).getDisplayValue() == "TRUE"){
  otherCells.forEach(o_cells=>{as.getRange(o_cells).setValue("FALSE")})}}
  );   
}
```

Please adjust the name of the sheet (`sheetName`) to the name of your own sheet.

---

### Instructions/Demonstration:

Please follow these instructions on how to set it up and use it:

- click on **Tools** => **Script editor**,
- **copy** and **paste** the code snippet to the code.gs file,
- and finally click on the **save** button.

[image: instructions]

---

### References:

**Google Apps Script:**

- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Spreadsheet Class](http://Class%20Spreadsheet)
- [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

**JavaScript:**

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Unrelated, how do you get dark mode in the editor @Marios?

Comment: @a-burge it is a chrome extension. Google something like dark mode Google script editor.

Comment: THANKS! This will save my eyes :)